# Express app returns "Cannot GET /" on routing with query parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to write the very simple nodejs express application, but it fails on routing request with query parameters. Here is a a very short code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('hello express');
});
app.get('/user/:id', (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.params.id);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Start listening at 3000');
});
```

The second "get" returns "Cannot GET /user".
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The second `GET` expects something like `/user/1`, `/user/arup` etc. The `:id` has to be replaced by something and it is **required** part of the url. That is why only `/user` gives you *404*. This is called dynamic url.

Comment: That is the request string: http://localhost:3000/user?id=abc What's wrong with it? And I don't get 404.

Answer (score 0):

The route `/user/:id` is not expecting *query* parameters but rather route parameters. Meaning it is expecting `/user/4384` not `/user?id=4384`

Answer (score -1):

#### You should try:

```
app.get('/user' && id, (req, res) => {
res.send(req.params.id);
});
```